# Django object creation happens infinitely

Tags: python, django, oop

I have a class connectTo defined in myclass.py which will connect to lets say a TCP socket and importing the same in views.py. I wrote an ajax to call the views function which creates object for my class as below

views.py

```
from myclasses import connectTo

def connect(request):
    connectTo()
    return JsonResponse("Success")
```

but the problem is as long as django server is running the connection to the TCP socket is happening. It should happen only once when connect in views.py is called instead it keeps on creating object and establishes TCP connection and stops if I close django server.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#connect').click(function (){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'connect/',
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            },
            success: function (output) {
            
            }
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: Looks like your JavaScript code is making a lot of AJAX calls. Can you share that part please?

Comment: I have added in the question, please have a look

Comment: even though I remove ajax and make on click render different html it is the same it creates multiple TCP connection for one call.

Comment: ok. JS parts looks ok. I guess then the issue must be in connectTo(). Can you share that code too please?

Comment: I got the issue. it is with the TCP connection which is happening in the constructor and also starting the connection to wait for server instead   I should create the connection object and start the connection from django views. Thanks